# Is 'init' forbidden as *part* of a variable name?

Tags: ios, swift

I just spent 3 hours debugging an error and in the end narrowed it down (I think) to the variable name.

I was using initMonths (initial months) which caused unpredicatable errors but when I changed to iMonths it worked!

I can understand preventing use of init on it's own but would be surprised if it is prevented just as part of a variable name. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: `let initMonths = 123; print(initMonths * 10)` works fine for me...

Comment: @TimVermeulen It seems to get past the compiler but causes unpredictable behaviour in applications. I was using initMonths as an object property and when I used those objects to populate UITableViewCells it would fall over around row 40 (though not consistently)

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily a bug if it's just related to the name being an overlap. There's a part of ARC used to know when retain counts should be updated, and you may be running into that.

Similar rules apply to the use `new` at the start of names (for the same reason).

It's certainly easy and wise to steer clear of using `init` at the start of any names unless it's actually an `init` function.

I can imagine that your issue could be related to ARC getting involved where it shouldn't and it takes a while for something to get called that shouldn't, but that would be weird.

I expect the issue is actually something else and that the name change had some other effect. Worst case it means you have a memory issue and that changing the name has changed the memory footprint of your code so you've just moved the bug somewhere else (or something along those lines).

Comment: I can use `init` and `new` at the start of variable names just fine?

Comment: Those naming conventions applied only (as far as I remember) to methods, not to variables.

Comment: Also seems to work fine for me. If this really causes unpredictable behaviour in some cases, I wouldn't say that it's not a bug.

Comment: I haven't run any tests just now to look at variables, and I haven't named anything like this for quite some time, but this is the only naming limitation I'm aware / can think of with `init`. The actual issue referred to in the question could be something completely unrelated of course... Fair point about the bug bit, and I should add a comment on naming too.